# Cant find right css tag

Tags: css

I am having real trouble trying to track down a blue border in a site at the min http://innovativeapps.dk/ you will see on top of the video its their but when I look on the css i cant find it.

```
.video-container .description .inner {   
   /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.79) none repeat scroll 0 0;*/   
   border-radius: 4px;   
   color: #ffffff;   
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 42px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 8px 25px;
   width: 68%;
}
```

Would anyone know where it is it almost looks like its in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code, there is a blue box shadow `box-shadow: 0 0 7px #1E70B9;` under `.navbar-default` in your `custom.css` file line no.47..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a shadow given in `navbar-default` in your `custom.css` file line no.47

```
.navbar-default {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #1E70B9; /*This is a blue shadow*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Box shadow is used to make border like shadows for any container mostly.
Its like text-shadow for text.

```
 navbar-default {
   background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
   **box-shadow: 0 0 7px #1E70B9; //this line make the blue shadow.**
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
 }
```